# Join operation in Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to create a Xpath expression for a join like operation based on common key

Here is my XML and I would like to get all the zone who has network name as

> 'network-2'

XML:

```
<tmp>
    <network>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>network-1</name>
    </network>
    <network>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>network-2</name>
    </network>
    <network>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>network-3</name>
    </network>
    <zone>
        <network-id>1</network-id>
        <zone-name>zone1</zone-name>
    </zone>
    <zone>
        <network-id>1</network-id>
        <zone-name>zone2</zone-name>
    </zone>
    <zone>
        <network-id>2</network-id>
        <zone-name>zone3</zone-name>
    </zone>
</tmp>
```

In network-id is foreign key for zone.

I tried with below xpath expression but it is not working:

```
/tmp/zone[contains(tmp/network/name,'network-2')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this part take id from the networ-2

```
/tmp/network[name[contains(., 'network-2')]]/id
```

and this finds zone name with that id

```
/tmp/zone[network-id= ?? ]/zone-name
```

full xpath may be so

```
/tmp/zone[network-id=/tmp/network[name[contains(., 'network-2')]]/id]/zone-name
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and explaination